Display vertex index with Geometry Nodes
How can I display the vertex index at the vertex position in Geometry Nodes? We can't use Value to String and String to Curves node because they don't support Field values.

@HarryMcKenzie your answer is good, the viewer has many limitations like the text being small and no occlusion which you often want.

@MarkusvonBroady cool thanks for your feedback. Ok I undeleted it just in case someone finds it useful. But I personally find the native approach looks nice enough.

@MarkusvonBroady I closed this question as a duplicate to ensure the original poster's contribution remains credited.

✲ Ctrl⬆ ShiftClick on geometry socket and then field socket (e.g. Index node) you want to preview, and then enable "Attribute Text" in overlay settings.


Side note: Not only Index, but any value (position vector e.g.) can be displayed this way.

There is a native solution shared by Markus, but you might also be interested in this free Index Viewer addon, which allows you to alter the text style in the custom group node. Just download the blend file and File > Append the custom node named Index Viewer Fields II [Append This] under NodeTree directory. I set the object to X-ray mode here so you can see the other indices:

